# How to verify the request is coming from my application clientside?

Tags: next.js

I have an app where users can create posts. **There is no login or user account needed**! They submit content with a form as post request. The post request refers to my api endpoint. I also have some other api points which are fetching data.

My goal is to protect the api endpoints completely except some specific sites who are allowed to request the api ( I want to accomplish this by having domain name and a secure string in my database which will be asked for if its valid or not if you call the api). This seems good for me. But I also need to make sure that my own application is still able to call the api endpoints. And there is my big problem. I have no idea how to implement this and I didn't find anything good.

So the api endpoints should only be accessible for:

Next.js Application itself if somebody does the posting for example
some other selected domains which are getting credentials which are saved in my database.
Hopefully somebody has an idea.

I thought to maybe accomplish it by using env vars, read them in `getinitalprops` and reuse it in my `post` request (on the client side it can't be read) and on my api endpoint its readable again. Sadly it doesn't work as expected so I hope you have a smart idea/code example how to get this working without using any account/login strategy because in my case its not needed.

index.js

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Home(props) {

  async function post()  {
    console.log(process.env.MYSECRET)
    const response = await fetch('/api/hello', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(process.env.MYSECRET),
    })

    if (!response.ok) {
      console.log(response.statusText)
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response))

    return await response.json().then(s => {
      console.log(s)
    })
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>

      <button onClick={post}>Press me</button>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  

    const myvar = process.env.MYSECRET

  return {
    props: { myvar },
  }
}
```

api

```
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

export default function handler(req, res) {
  const mysecret = req.body
  res.status(200).json({ name: mysecret })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to create an API without user authentication and protect it from requests that are not coming from your client application.

First of all, I prefer to warn you, unless you only authorize requests coming from certain IPs (be careful with IP Spoofing methods which could bypass this protection), this will not be possible. If you set up an API key that is shared by all clients, reverse engineering or sniffing HTTP requests will retrieve that key and impersonate your application.

To my knowledge, there is no way to counter this apart from setting up a user authentication system.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I want to save the domain name as username and a token as password in my database and send this credentials to the partners who are allowed to access the api endpoint which will look up the credentials in my database. I would follow the same concept with my application itself, but I cant create this data for my application because on the clientside there is my post form for example and I have to place the credentials there too and then everyone can read it. Thats where im struggling.

Comment: Yes that is indeed the problem, and I think there are no solutions without authentication. When a domain makes a request, you can be pretty sure it is reliable (Unless the domain has been compromised). But if you distribute an app you can't protect it in the same way.

Comment: hm there has to be a solution somehow. imagine all the platforms which dont provide account creation but still need to do a post for example. I could take the code from the api endpoint and place it in a function on the clientside but my problem is that im using prisma(database ORM) and nodemailer for example and both dont work on clientside from what i know. Or do you have an idea how to do so?

Comment: That only works on api endpoints, getinitialprops and getserversideprops. But the function will be executed if the button is pressed

Comment: Can you provide an example of platforms that provide possibility to post something without any authentification ? 

It's possible to make it a lot harder by using timestamp + salt hashing verifications, ect ... but in finallity, it's impossible to make it unreeversable

Comment: can we call a function which needs to be executed serverside without the use of api endpoints in nextjs? (Let me think of a platform meanwhile :D )

Comment: How want you call a serverside function from client without any api request (It's possible using another protocol like TCP socket but it's the same result for security)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234442/discussion-between-marcel-dz-and-0x0000000000000).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have been doing it on my NextJS webapp.

Many my API endpoints require authentication so I use the user session to verify the user is logged in and that the cookie/session matches the user ID attempting the request.

Steps

1. You need setup a session/authentication with the webapp in general. In my case after the user uses the correct email and password. I generate a random 128 random alphanumeric string and place it into their cookie. I then save that 128 alphanumeric string and their user ID into a session document on our database. I now have my general authentication structure.
2. The user needs to login and have that alphanumeric string in their cookies. Keep in mind all our API endpoints have access to the cookies and access to that alphanumeric string.
3. Each endpoint request I get that alphanumeric string cookie from the req.headers. I also require the user ID is passed with every request. I find the session using alphanumeric string and user ID, if it exists and is valid, not expired etc, the user gets access to the endpoint otherwise throw an error

Hope this helps

Welcome any thoughts or points from the community !

Daniel